# missing paperclip when i am run server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip

I have problem with paperclip

```
sudo rails server
Could not find paperclip-3.3.1 in any of the sources
Run `bundle install` to install missing gems.
```

But paperclip is intalled.
Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It may be installed, but not available to your gem, or an incompatible version. Run the following commands from your app root:

```
bundle install
bundle exec rails s
```